# What's the difference between Virtual functions and normal functions?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Few concepts in C++ such as Virtual functions have always been playing with my head since the beginning. I've read a few syntaxes of the virtual functions, but I could never understand -

1. What virtual functions do
2. Why are they used? I mean practically
3. Why do we need them? Can't we use ordinary functions instead?
4. Can anybody explain what the following functions are declared for?

   ```
   void MakeMeASandwich();

   virtual void MakeMeASandwich();

   virtual void MakeMeASandwich() = 0;
   ```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_functions

Comment: @Blastfurnace not even close.

Comment: There are many multiple questions on SO explaining what virtual functions are, how they are used, and what those declarations mean. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: My question is specific enough, I've asked whats the difference between the three functions that's been given in the code blocks.

Comment: What's your problem?

What virtual functions do?
Why are they used? I mean practically
Why do we need them? Can't we use ordinary functions instead?
Can anybody explain what the following functions are declared for?

I've checked ever post on stack overflow for the answers that I've been looking for. I never found any, I asked 4 simple,readable questions which I've been struggling with. Anybody can type in the search bar and accuse people of possible duplicates, next time try understanding the question rather than blindly accusing the users that its plagiarized or reposted.

Comment: I just tried to point out that SO is a large resource and you might be able to answer your own question using the Search function a little. I didn't realize you already "checked ever post". Have a nice day.

Comment: The wikipedia entry I linked answers all of those questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    void Y() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
    virtual void X() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void Y() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
    virtual void X() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.Y(); // "A"
  a.X(); // "A"

  B b;
  b.Y(); // "B"
  b.X(); // "B"

  A* ap = &b;
  ap->Y(); // "A"
  ap->X(); // "B"
}
```

Virtual functions are not that interesting if you're not into polymorphy and deriving. As you see, in the third case the instance of B is accessed via a pointer of type `A*`. With non-virtual functions this means that functions called are actually defined in `A`, not in `B`. Virtual function calls are resolved with a table, so the code *at runtime* determines where to jump.

To your questions:

1) Determining at runtime, which function is to be called, depending on the *real* type of the object.

2) Polymorphy

3) No, as `ap->X()` would call `A::X()` if it were not for `virtual`.

4) With pleasure:

`void MakeMeASandwich();` default, nothing special.

`virtual void MakeMeASandwich();` a virtual function, providing an implementation. Deriving classes may choose to override it.

`virtuall void MakeMeASandwich() = 0;` a virtual function is declared, but no implementation is provided. The class containing this function is automatically set to be `abstract` and can't be instantiated.

Comment: If you have more questions, please ask. `Virtual` functions are not that easy to understand...

Comment: @thriqon Is it correct to add that a pure virtual method requires a subclass to provide an implementation of the pure virtual method, where as the other two do not?  The "Interfaces" of C++?

Comment: @johnny Yes your right about the forced implementation of pure virtual methods.